# Training loss increasing with more samples, while validation loss decreases

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm trying to build a model to predict the duration of my daily walk, and the dataset is small (around 250 observations). I've sourced a ton of features (100+), which I guess for a small dataset could lead to overfitting, but I suspect that many of them aren't adding much value.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to proceed, and I've plotted a learning curve with all of the features - using Ridge Regression - but I'm not entirely sure on the correct interpreation. Essentially the train error is increasing with additional samples, while the validation error is decreasing, and I'm not sure what that tells me about how to proceed.

[image: Learning curve]

Any advice would be welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like maybe you have trends in time. Some people don’t walk as much in the winter. If they’re trying to make a model that accounts for winter time walking and summer time walking then they need at least a year if not more to be able to account for the difference in the seasonality.

Comment: Thanks @EngrStudent. The data spans more than a year, it just has some days missing where I didn't walk. I have a lot of weather-related variables as well, which provide information on seasonality and are basically the bulk of the features.

Comment: Do you have variables like "week of year", "hour of day", "day of week", "is weekend" and "is holiday" in your inputs?  There can be multiple types of "seasonality".

Comment: I have the start time of the walk (which covers the hour) and whether I was at work or not (so weekends and days off are treated the same). I don't have week of year as I think the specific week is probably less relevant than the conditions on each individual day.

Comment: don't tell the data what to do.  ;)  Week isn't relevant, but it has the subtlety that it encodes both large-scale seasonal stuff like summer vs. winter, as well as small-scale seasonal stuff in that it is about how long it takes a mesoscale storm to pass.  People behave different on weekends/holidays vs. weekdays. People aren't as interested in jogging at heat of peak summer day or depth of coldest winter night, so hour of day plays a part too.